# What do you think of One tab element on a tab menu

Tags: layout, filter, tabs

I am doing the UX design of a complex system that requires filtering in different pages.

The filtering menu is in tabs: time, status, name, place, etc... are all different tabs on the left.  I could exemplify it as, for facebook I would have a different set of filters for newsfeed (person, date, place, etc...), and a different set of filters for my profile (friend group, person, place, occasion...).

On one page I have only one element left in the tab group, so there is only one element on thee left.... Which to me looks very useless and I want to make it a stand alone page and modify it if there ever is another criteria.

What do you think? Why should I keep the tab structure? Or not? For the sake of consistency within the system? Shall I make a page that has only one selection option :)

Answer (score 1):

Tabs are *usually* used when there are more than 2 sections of the same context.
Although, in that case, where a page has only one section, but it is part of the system, the one tab can be kept for consistency, predictability and scalability. A page with a different layout sometimes indicates different context.

A useful article about tab controls
http://www.nngroup.com/articles/tabs-used-right/

Comment: Thank you Stevy. The resource will definitely help a lot. NNgroup is always very convincing.